# How to Call a method Using Non UI thread(Without Affecting UI thread) in Andorid

Tags: java, android, multithreading

1.I am fetching some data from a database showing in Android ListView, when a button gets clicked.

2.Whenever the background process is running it's not working properly. I've searched my Code it is running in Main UI thread, thats why my database data is not received properly.

3.I want to run this code outside of a UI thread.(Normal Thread or Async task)

4.Please help me on how to do this.

code I want to run in Non UI Thread:

```
private void output() 
{       
                            if(Popup__output.equals("All"))
                            {
                          //for delete a item in List view
                            helper.open();

                            new Handler().post(new Runnable() 
                            {

                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    cur = helper.getCategory(Popup__output,Sharedemail);

                                    myCursorAdap = new Cursoradapterfor__page(Page1_Landing.this, cur);

                                    List.setAdapter(myCursorAdap);

                                     popupWindowvariable.dismiss();
                                }


                            });

                            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this better you can use android `AsyncTask` where you can get data in `doInBackground()` method and the UI work like setting adapter and dismissing progressview must be done on UI-thread so `AsyncTask` provide you `onPostExecute()` method where you can perform UI related operation.

For more detail about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: thank you,  also want to check other some conditions fetch data from database. for this purpose i want to use multiple Asynctask ,else keep it in Single Async task?

Comment: if you can want it for same activity you can do or you have same output then you can make global function you can manage it in single asynctask also